# Some conflicts were found in the installation area, while updating android studio 3.0.1

Tags: java, android, xml, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I am getting this error while updating Android Studio 3.0.1 some patch gets downloaded and following error comes,

Some of the conflicts below do not have a solution, so the patch cannot be applied.

Showing File : jre/bin/java.exe is Absent

[image: screenshot of the error while updating android studio 3.0.1]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If anyone is still having this issue, here's what worked for me. I checked a bunch of other responses but nothing worked & I didn't want to do a clean install.

Not sure how it happened, but within my Android_Studio\jre\ was another jre version. So, I went into Android_Studio\jre\jre\bin\, copied the java.exe from there & pasted it into Android_Studio\jre\bin.

Similar solution to the other poster, but it had to come from a different directory, otherwise it'll just change from "Absent" to "modified" & continue to not work.

Comment: The same problem after copying `java.exe`.

Comment: I had the same issue while trying to update studio 3.6.1.The solution Worked like a charm!

Comment: Same issue while updating Android Studio 3.6.3. Found java.exe in jre/jre/bin and worked. Thanks

Comment: This solution worked for me like a charm! while upgrading from android 3.5.3 to 4.0.1

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I've just copied `java.exe` from jdk installed folder (e.g. `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe`) to `Android_Studio\jre\bin`, and Android Studio had upgraded successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, solved in that way: I just reinstalled my current Android Studio version (without losing any settings, etc) and then tried to update again. Everything went fine after that.

Answer (score 2):

Opened Android Studio again and choose update and restart option. Once the download is completed, the android studio is closed automatically and an update window appeared on the screen. At that time I opened the terminal and entered the following command:

**`ps -A | grep java`**

That command showed all the running java related processes. Now I killed those processes using the following command:

**`kill -9 PID`**

Replace PID with the corresponding process id.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to modification of java installed files. Download the latest android studio and reinstall it. The previous configuration can be restored during the reinstall over existing version.